# What is the use of bincount() method from numpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

What is its purpose? I tried reading the official site but wasn't able to understand.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[`bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) returns the **count** of values in each [**bin**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) from 0 to the largest value in the array i.e.

```py
np.bincount(my_list) == [count(i) for i in range(0, max(my_list))]
                     == [count(0), count(1), ..., count(max(my_list))]
```

e.g.

```py
np.bincount([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 6])
>>>   array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1])
```

---

**Note:**

- absent numbers (e.g. `5` above) return a count of `0`
- a `ValueError` is raised if the list contains negative numbers or `NaN`

Answer (score 16):

Here's a [graphic explanation](https://appdividend.com/2022/01/29/np-bincount/) of `bincount()` with and without weights:

[image]